# POI XWPFTable inserted but not shown in Word document

Tags: scala, ms-word, apache-poi, docx

POI version 3.16-beta1

I am trying to insert a XWPFTable object into an existing XWPFDocument instance.

```
  val doc = new XWPFDocument()
  val doc2 = new XWPFDocument()
  val tb = doc.createTable(3,3)
  val tb2 = doc2.createTable(4,4)
  val pos = doc.getPosOfTable(tb)
  doc.insertTable(pos+1, tb2)
  val out = new java.io.FileOutputStream(
    new java.io.File("./test/resources/document_output.docx")
  )
  doc.write(out)
  out.close()
```

but document_output.docx has only the first table, tb. tb2 does not appear in the Word document.
Could anyone see why?

Comment: `XWPFDocument.insertTable()` does not do what you think it should. In fact, it should be an internal method because it deals with the internal structures of an `XWPFDocument` object, but does not insert a table into the body of the document. Why not just create a second table?

Comment: Thanks jmarkmurphy.  I was misunderstanding the method specification.